# ComponentDidUpdate is not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do `setState` in the `componentDidUpdate`.
I did some research and read that I have to put some condition before making `setState` so it wont create forever loop but it did not work.

Any suggestions please?

Here is my code

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
const { isAuthenticated, navigation,actions } = this.props;
try {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'AlternatePhrase' });
    this.setState({isCreating:false})
  }
} catch (e) {
    console.log('--------e', e);
}
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component  repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [docs for componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and you'll see that you're given access to `prevProps`.  The `condition` to avoid a loop is to check to see if `isAuthenticated` changed during the update and only if it did, then continue with your flow:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { isAuthenticated, navigation } = this.props;
  if (prevProps.isAuthenticated !== isAuthenticated) {
    try {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'AlternatePhrase' });
        this.setState({isCreating:false})
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('--------e', e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I will be able to accept ur answer in several min